# What is the difference between "cvs update" and "cvs -n update"?

Tags: version, cvs

What is the difference between "cvs update" and "cvs -n update"?

I couldn't understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that

```
cvs update
```

does an actual update, while

```
cvs -n update
```

simulates an update and won't change anything on disk. It will only show which files would be updated if you did an actual update.

Quoting the CVS documentation (for version 1.12.13):

```
`-n'
     Do not change any files.  Attempt to execute the `cvs_command',
     but only to issue reports; do not remove, update, or merge any
     existing files, or create any new files.

     Note that CVS will not necessarily produce exactly the same output
     as without `-n'.  In some cases the output will be the same, but
     in other cases CVS will skip some of the processing that would
     have been required to produce the exact same output.
```

Comment: What do you mean by actual update? Do I update the files in repository or in my working copy? If it is actual update, then waht is the difference between "cvs update" and "cvs checkin" and "cvs checkout"?

Comment: @alwbtc 'cvs update' updates your local working copy from the remote repository, so does 'cvs checkout' (which acts pretty much like 'cvs update -d'. 'cvs checkout' is generally used to check out an initial version of a project while 'cvs update' is used to update the local copy once you have it. 'cvs checkin' doesn't even exist in my cvs command, I've never used it so can't speak for it.

Comment: sorry, i think it was "cvs commit", not "cvs checkin", right? Would you please expound "initial version of a project"? Doesn't it checkout the latest version of the project?

Comment: @alwbtc Yes, 'cvs commit' will update the repository from your local working copy, that is the exact opposite of 'cvs update'.

Comment: Thanks, but "cvs co sample_file" will also update "sample_file" file in my working copy. What is the difference between "cvs co sample_file" and "cvs update sample_file"?

Comment: @alwbtc As I said in an earlier comment, 'cvs checkout' and 'cvs update' are pretty much the same ('cvs checkout' is afaik exactly the same as 'cvs update -d'), but they have some extra options that are more suited for different purposes. Usually 'cvs checkout' has better options for a first checkout, while 'cvs update' has better options for updating an existing working copy.

Answer (score -1):

"-n: Do not run any tag program. (A program can be specified to run in the modules database (see section The modules file); this option bypasses it). "

http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs_16.html#SEC117

Comment: I think you're talking about cvs update -n, not cvs -n update (entirely different option)